# Deploy The YOLOv5 Model With Tensorflow Lite

Tags: android-studio, image-processing, object-detection, tensorflow-lite, yolo

I want to make an application that guesses the name of the selected food image. I used yolov5. Output is correct on test images in colab.
I'm testing with the same image.
https://colab.research.google.com/github/ultralytics/yolov5/blob/master/tutorial.ipynb
I created the yolov5s-fp16.lite file from here.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tySgZ1rEbW4
I followed this video for it to work on android platform.

my tf lite file on android

```
try {
    Yolov5sFp16 model = Yolov5sFp16.newInstance(context);

    // Creates inputs for reference.
    TensorBuffer inputFeature0 = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(new int[]{1, 640, 640, 3}, DataType.FLOAT32);
    inputFeature0.loadBuffer(byteBuffer);

    // Runs model inference and gets result.
    Yolov5sFp16.Outputs outputs = model.process(inputFeature0);
    TensorBuffer outputFeature0 = outputs.getOutputFeature0AsTensorBuffer();

    // Releases model resources if no longer used.
    model.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Handle the exception
}
```

predictBtn

```
predictBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
            public void onClick(View view){

                try {
                    Yolov5sFp16 model = Yolov5sFp16.newInstance(MainActivity.this);

                    // Creates inputs for reference.
                    TensorBuffer inputFeature0 = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(new int[]{4, 640, 640, 3}, DataType.FLOAT32);
                    Log.d("shape", inputFeature0.toString());

                    bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 640 ,640,true );

                     inputFeature0.loadBuffer(TensorImage.fromBitmap(bitmap).getBuffer());

                    // Runs model inference and gets result.
                    Yolov5sFp16.Outputs outputs = model.process(inputFeature0);

                    TensorBuffer outputFeature0 = outputs.getOutputFeature0AsTensorBuffer();


                    result.setText(labels[getMax(outputFeature0.getFloatArray())]+" ");

                     // Releases model resources if no longer used.
                    model.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Handle the exception
                }




            }
        });
    }
```

ERROR

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplicationdeploy, PID: 6744
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The size of byte buffer and the shape do not match.
        at org.tensorflow.lite.support.common.SupportPreconditions.checkArgument(SupportPreconditions.java:104)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.support.tensorbuffer.TensorBuffer.loadBuffer(TensorBuffer.java:309)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.support.tensorbuffer.TensorBuffer.loadBuffer(TensorBuffer.java:328)
        at com.example.myapplicationdeploy.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:108)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1194)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

When I debug, it gives an error in the buffer part. What should I do? What should the dimensions be?